# Preg match all won't find the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

My `preg_match_all` function:

```
preg_match_all("{lang:(.*?)}", $template, $found_langs);
```

The template is like:

```
<h1>{lang:Choose sport}</h1>
```

But it won't find it... BUT if I use this:

```
preg_match_all("{lang:(\w*)}", $template, $found_langs);
```

It'll find `Choose`. I need to find `Choose sport`..

Anyone knows why `(.*?)` won't work?

Comment: FYI, you'd have better performance using `[^\}]+`.

Comment: Don't forget that http://regex101.com is your friend ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to escape `{` char and use `//` for RegEx pattern in [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all("/\{lang:(.*?)\}/i", $template, $found_langs);
```

And `//i` at the end of pattern is a case insensitivity.